# TSQL-JOIN: display non-existing values in one table as zero in Join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables:

**ProjectProduct** (two IDs for project and product) and

**ProductStatus** (which contains quality ratings for products).

Table: **ProjectProduct**

```
| productID | projectID |
| --------- | --------- |
| 39        | 26        |
| 40        | 26        |
| 41        | 26        |
| 42        | 26        |
```

Table: **ProductStatus**

```
| id  | projectID | productID | typeID | Status | Comment      | RatedBy |
| --- | --------- | --------- | ------ | ------ | ------------ | ------- |
| 1   | 26        | 39        | 2      | 30     | comm1        | 0       |
| 2   | 26        | 39        | 2      | 70     | comm2        | 0       |
| 22  | 26        | 39        | 1      | 70     | diff type    | 0       |
| 3   | 26        | 39        | 2      | 100    | comm3        | 0       |
| 4   | 26        | 39        | 2      | 70     | diff ratedBy | 1       |
| 5   | 26        | 39        | 2      | 100    | comm5        | 0       |
| 6   | 26        | 39        | 2      | 30     | comm6        | 0       |
```

I need to join those two tables so that every product in the ProjectProduct table will display a Status value even if there is **no corosponding entry** in the ProductStatus table.

In above example only **productID** 39 exists in both tables. To show all productIDs the output should contain a **zero value** in the Status column for productIDs 40 to 42.
This is the part that I cannot figure out. For example the ProductStatus TypeID can contain 1 or 2. TypeID 2 has to be distinguished between RatedBy which can contain 0 or 1. Do I need the table or select statement to reflect all possible permutations?

Also only the row with the highest ID grouped by projectID, productID, typeID, RatedBy should be picked where there is an existing rating.

**Desired output**:
[image]

I also created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f3288/1)

I hope you can guide me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you write your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**

```
   SELECT ProjectProduct.projectID,  ProjectProduct.productID, ProductStatus.typeid,ProductStatus.status,ProductStatus.Comment,ProductStatus.ratedBY
    FROM      ProjectProduct  
    left join 
    (
    SELECT max(ID) id, productID,projectID
    FROM  ProductStatus
    where typeID = 2 
    and ratedBY = 0
    group BY productID,projectID ) maxproduct on ProjectProduct.productID = maxproduct.productID and ProjectProduct.projectID = maxproduct.projectID
    left join ProductStatus on ProductStatus.id = maxproduct.ID
```

**Output**
[image: Output]

Comment: thank you. this one is the easiest (for me) of all examples and it works very nicely.

Comment: Welcome! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

you can use temp table like that:

```
select Max(Id) maxID ,ProductId,ProjectId into #Temp1 from ProductStatus 
where typeID=2 and RatedBy=0
group by ProductId,ProjectId

select * into #Temp2 from ProductStatus  where Id In (select MaxId from #Temp1)

select p.ProjectId,p.ProductId, 2 as typeID,isnull(t.status,0) as Status,t.Comment,0 as RatedBy 
from ProjectProduct p left join #Temp2 t on p.ProductId=t.ProductId and p.ProjectId=t.ProjectId
```